# Storing single csv line object into arrays

Tags: java, arrays, object, csv, java-io

hey ive got a chunk of code here trying to read a single line in a .csv file:

rows = new WarehouseItem[];

```
public void readCSV(String filename) {
  FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
  InputStreamReader rdr;
  BufferedReader bufRdr;
  int lineNum;
  String line;

  try {
    fileStrm = new FileInputStream(filename);
    rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
    bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);

    numRows = 0;
    line = bufRdr.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
      rows[numRows] = line;
      numRows++;
      line = bufRdr.readLine();
  }
  fileStrm.close();
  }

  catch (IOException e) {
    if (fileStrm != null) {
      try { 
    fileStrm.close(); 
      } catch (IOException ex2) {}
    }
    System.out.println("Error in file processing: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
```

on the `rows[numRows] = line` im trying to store the line into an array of objects(i have premade an object which contains an array of strings and the number of columns)

im not entirely sure how to store the single line im trying to read in my object.

any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: The declaration of `rows` is missing from your code snippet. We need to see that, please.

Comment: You need to tell us what `rows` _is_. Is it a `String[]`? A `String[][]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your life would be an awful lot easier if you used a CSV library to do this.  With jackson it's really simple to read CSV into an array of objects.

For example:

```
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
mapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY);
File csvFile = new File("input.csv"); // or from String, URL etc
MappingIterator<Object[]> it = mapper.reader(Object[].class).readValues(csvFile);
```

See here for more info on parsing CSV in java: http://demeranville.com/how-not-to-parse-csv-using-java/